# In ASP.NET MVC, how do I check if a property has an error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've got the following bit of Razor code in MVC5.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Name</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
</div>
```

I now want to make sure that if `Name` has an error, the form group div gets a `has-error` class. How can I check if the Name property has an error?

Edit: As requested here's a more complete version of the view I'm working with.

```
@model CaptchaMvc.Models.DefaultBuildInfoModel

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.InputElementId, "Retype the characters in the image", new { @class = "control-label", @for = "CaptchaInputText" })

    <div class="input-group">
        <span style="padding:0;overflow:hidden;" class="input-group-addon">
            @Html.Hidden(Model.TokenElementId, Model.TokenValue)
            <img style="margin:-12px" id="@Model.ImageElementId" src="@Model.ImageUrl" alt="Captcha Text" />
        </span>
        @Html.TextBox(Model.InputElementId, null, new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {"data-val", "true"},
            {"data-val-required", Model.RequiredMessage},
            {"class", "form-control"},
            {"style", "width: 200px;"},
            {"placeholder", "Retype captcha"}
        })
    </div>
</div>
```

It's a partial view for use with CaptchaMvc. It's included in a form the following way.

```
@Html.Captcha(6, "_Captcha")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're already using the Unobtrusive Validation plugin, you can extend it with a Bootstrap-enabled plugin:

https://github.com/sandrocaseiro/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.bootstrap

or, via NuGet:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.bootstrap/

Once that's loaded, everything should happen automagically. Just make sure the libraries are loaded in the correct order:

```
<script src="/path/to/jquery"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.unobtrusive.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

It's worth noting that client validation only works if your model has the correct annotations; here's an example:

```
public class CommentFormModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Your name")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "This field is required.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Your email? (optional)"), DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    [Display(Name = "Content")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "This field is required.")]
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This instantly worked, I'm very impressed with the work already done here and how well it immediately slots in. As an added bonus, how can I make it mark a field with `has-error` on submit press if it's blocking submitting? Currently it just focuses the field which threw me off a bit as I didn't realize yet why it wasn't submitting.

Comment: @LaylConway The validate plugin, ultimately, adds hooks to the submit event, and cancels the event if validation fails. However, I'm not entirely sure what you're asking; do you mean that the error styles aren't applying?

Comment: The error style is applying but only after the form has already been submitted and the page has reloaded with an error. It's however not applying an error if I try to submit the form without anything in the text field, in that case it's simply focusing the text field.

Comment: @LaylConway If you're not seeing error messages, it's because you need to add `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.YourProperty)`. Are the model properties annotated, and are you using `@using(Html.BeginForm(...))`? If you don't mind, please edit your question to include a more complete example of your view.

Comment: I edited the question and added the view. The validation message does show up if I add it, but the form-group does not get a `has-error` added, causing it to not be marked red.

Comment: @LaylConway Hmm. I'll have to see if I can replicate this. The plugin isn't doing anything complicated, so it should just work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59393/discussion-between-tieson-t-and-layl-conway).

Comment: @LaylConway I left some notes in the chat linked to above. Let me know if you need me to expand on what's there.

Answer (score 10):

A very simplistic server side check for an error on a field would be:

`@ViewData.ModelState.IsValidField("Name")`

Returns `true/false`, depending on whether the Name field has an errors related to it.

EDIT:

```
@{ 
    var nameHasError = Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name) != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name).ToString());
}
```

Comment: Is there an alternative that uses an expression to get the property I could use?

Comment: _Kind of_ yeah. Edited my answer. Not quite as tidy, but should work.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it works with just standard MVC

Answer (score 3):

```
@if(ViewData.ModelState.IsValidField(nameof(Model.Property)))
{
     // Do some thing
}
else
{
     // Do some thing else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use DataAnnotations in your model to get this to work.

A description of a similar implementation is in the link below:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/validation-using-data-annotation-to-custom-model-or-class/

Comment: While this would be a solution to this simplified example, it does not apply to the more complex case I'm dealing with, as the model is not within my project.

Answer (score 0):

Html.ViewContext.ModelState[fieldname].ValidationState